# Почему open xml добавляет параграф как OpenXMLUnknownElement?

Tags: c#, docx, openxml

Использую Open XML для работы с .docx файлами.
У меня метод, возвращающий параграф:

```
private Paragraph GetParagraph()
{
    var par = new Paragraph();
    var run = new Run();
    var text = new Text("Sample text");

    run.Append(text);
    par.Append(run);

    return par;
}
```

Дальше я пытаюсь добавить этот параграф перед каждым параграфом в документе:

```
using (var wpd = WordprocessingDocument.Open(file, true))
{
    var body = wpd.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

    foreach (var par in body)
    {
        body.InsertBefore(GetParagraph(), par);
    }
}
```

И у меня он добавляется не как тип Paragraph, а как OpenXMLUnknownElement почему-то. Соответственно, в документе их не видно, но они есть, я это вижу через Open XML SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Дело оказалось в том, что такой тип, похоже, есть в разных пространствах имен. Когда я подключил вот этот неймспейс `using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;`, все заработало.